# What is the optimal size for photos in a digital portfolio?

Tags: portfolio

Currently most of the pictures that I want to put into a my portfolio are around 3000 x 5000 px. It is obvious that most people don't have a screen resolution even close to this. Is there a standard size for online photos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The optimal size depends on a lot of things.** The intended audience, the quality of your work, the license you use and the watermark if applicable.

Most of **my professional friends limit themselves to about 600x600** to avoid illegal copying. This obvisously limits the ability to appreciate photographic details but [this is the one I chose too](http://www.neoluminance.com/) because people steal online images constantly.

Unfortunately photo buyers sometimes as for full-size (or close to) previews in which case you can use a service with private access to show these.

If you want to give **an immersive experience you will need a higher resolution**. A minimum of 900px on the wide side but up to 1400px would not me unreasonable. In that case  you will probably want to place an intrusive watermark over the center/subject of the image or content yourself if an open licence which, sadly, will probably not be respected anyway.

Online images get copied and even printed, so limiting to a small size which cannot be used printed is key to keep your property from being abused.

Comment: Watermarking is overrated.  If you don't want to share, then keep your images locked in a closet offline.  If they're not obtrusive, watermarks won't stop a determined image thief.  If they are obtrusive, then visitors won't want to see your photos.

Comment: Look at any stock image site and you will see that watermarks are a necessity. Most of my professional photographer friends would agree, that is a topic we covered at length between us all the times some photo was misused. With a watermark, there is much more chance of getting compensated for a misused image.

Comment: But the audience of a stock photography site is not everyone's audience. I agree if you're doing stock photography — in that case, watermark away.

Comment: No, but the same protection applies of any photography of value.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the majority of people browsing the web are using monitors with a resolution around 1366x768.

http://www.useit.com/alertbox/screen_resolution.html

I'm at 1920x1200.

So what I've done is set the largest side to 950 pixels, and let the smallest one fall where it will.